# View hats progress

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

Unless I misunderstood something, hats were based off the XBox "achievement unlocked" model. Given that, is there a way to check in on my hats progress?

Even if it was not based off the XBox "achievement unlocked" model, since hats are only around for a limited time, is there a way to check in on my hats progress?

Comment: i wish this feature for all badge too...

Comment: I don't really check and didn't even read the description for all hats. I let it be a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login at http://winterba.sh/ and scroll down a little. You will see all the hats you have unlocked.

If you mean your progress on individual hats then the answer is **no**. Just like most badges, you can not check the progress you have made so far.

[image: hatprogress]